# i am getting 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. a5sm29349940pbw.4 - gsmtp error while send a mail from java program, how to solve it?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

### Error:

```
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. a5sm29349940pbw.4 - gsmtp

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1829)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1368)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:886)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:191)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:120)
at com.conceptbuild.EmailGenerator.main(EmailGenerator.java:120)
```

### Code:

```
package com.conceptbuild;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.RecipientType;

public class EmailGenerator {

    public EmailGenerator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private class MailAuthenticator extends Authenticator {

        String username = "username";

        String password = "password";

        public MailAuthenticator() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)   {

        String host="smtp.gmail.com";
        String from="fromaddress";
        String to="toaddress";
        String cc="ccaddress";
        Address fromaddress=null,toaddress=null,ccaddress=null;

        Properties mailproperties= new Properties();

        mailproperties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        mailproperties.put("mail.smtp.port", 25);
        mailproperties.put("mail.debug", "true");
        mailproperties.put("mail.transport.protocal", "smtps");
        mailproperties.put("mail.smtp.STARTTLS.enable", "true");
        mailproperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        mailproperties.put("mail.smtps.**ssl.enable", "false");
        mailproperties.setProperty("mail.smtps.**ssl.required", "false");

        EmailGenerator emailgenerator= new EmailGenerator();

        MailAuthenticator auth= emailgenerator.new MailAuthenticator();

        Session session = Session.getInstance(mailproperties, auth);

        try {
             fromaddress= new InternetAddress(from,"Sushant Wadjikar");
             toaddress= new InternetAddress(to);
             ccaddress=new InternetAddress(cc);

        }catch (AddressException ex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        Message message= new MimeMessage(session);

        try {
            message.setFrom(fromaddress);
            message.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, toaddress);
            message.setRecipient(RecipientType.CC, ccaddress);
            message.setSubject("Hello !!! My First Mail from my java program");
            message.setSentDate(new Date());
            message.setText("Good Morning"+"\n"+"This is my first mail, sending it from my java program"+"\n"+"Thanks and Regards"+"\n"+"Sushant");

            Transport transport;
            transport = session.getTransport("smtp");

            transport.connect();

            message.saveChanges();

            transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Mail send successfully.........");

        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have u include the jar means mail provider jar into the class path??

Comment: change port from 25 to 587

Answer (score 5):

[This](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#send) will likely fix your problem.

Also, make up your mind on whether you're using the "smtp" protocol or the "smtps" protocol and name the properties accordingly.  And there are no properties with "**" in their names.

---

To quote:

Q: How do I use SSL or TLS when connecting to my mail server?

A: To use SMTP over SSL, set the mail.smtp.ssl.enable property in the Session properties. To use the STARTTLS command set the mail.smtp.starttls.enable property in the Session properties. For example:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
// or: props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
// set message content here
Transport.send(msg, username, password);
```

Comment: perfect. I had the same thing, becoz by mistake I wrote:   javaMailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", true); instead of   javaMailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");